# main.xml: Failed to parse file

Tags: android

I'm developing a test application for Android, and I'm trying to add a custom image to a button. But when I try to save I get the error "main.xml: Failed to parse file C:\Program Files\Eclipse Workspace\App\res\drawable\custom_button.xml". I don't know how to solve it. I think both main.xml and custom_button.xml are correct.

custom_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For making this, I followed these two tutorials:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

And:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: What happens when you try to launch it anyway?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong in your xml files. I would suggest deleting custom_button.xml and re-creating it and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project (Project --> Clean) and restarting eclipse? sometimes that magically works...

Comment: did you try changing `encoding="UTF-8"` to `encoding="utf-8"`. i've never tried this before, but it might be that the "UTF-8" value is case-sensitive.

Comment: Cleaning the project worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but since I dont have comment perm I will write it here anyways.
Maybe `"@drawable/button_pressed"` or the other drawable may not be present.

Or like already said in the comment try recreating it. I have had this problem previously. And make sure that if you are copy pasting, not to include any invalid characters.

Comment: Thanks folks :) After cleaning, recreating and restarting eclipse the problem was magically solved.

Comment: @user1158998 would be glad if you could accept the answer if you found it useful.